# How do I know if Orbot's proxying is forcing apps to use it?

Tags: orbot, android

I have Orbot installed and my tablet rooted and Orbot has been given permission to run with superuser privileges. I have chosen my apps to put on Tor through Orbot and they work fine. However, when I use the apps no data usage is reported by Orbot's system tray monitor.
How can I be sure there is no data leakage?

Comment: You'd need to intercept the outbound traffic from the phone and look for it to be sure.

Comment: Do the apps really need and use your Internet connection? I made the experience that the OrBot VPN needs to be restarted from time to time, because it stops forwarding connections.

Comment: VPN is spotty at best. Restarting did not fix issue for me. Apps could no longer connect. So I guess the VPN doesn't leak